# Solving arithmetic operations

Tags: c#, math

```
int a = 3, b = 9, c = 2;
double e = 11, f = 0.1;

e = (b + c) / a * a;
```

Now, I want to now what the result of `e`  is. When I do the math in my head, I get the result to be `11/9 = 1,22222222`

BUT

when I run the program in the compiler, I simply get 9. Which way to think is right?

Answer (score 7):

There are 2 thing going wrong,

- your misunderstanding your order of operations
- your integers are truncating

so, what the compiler is doing is

- 9+2 = 11
- 11/3 = 3.666 truncated to 3
- 3*3 = 9

Use parenthesis, and don't use ints, use all doubles.

```
double a = 3, b = 9, c = 2, d;
double e = 11, f = 0.1;
string s = "AB", t = "BA", v;

            e = (b + c) / (a * a);
```

---

if a, b, and c all have to be ints, than you can cast them

```
int a = 3, b = 9, c = 2, d;
double e = 11, f = 0.1;
string s = "AB", t = "BA", v;

            e = ((double)b + (double)c) / ((double)a * (double)a);
```

now this could just easily be done with

```
e = (double)(b + c) / (double)(a * a);
```

and that's because both operations in parenthesis leave no remainder, but it is a bad practice to rely on those kind of coincidences.

Comment: You have a point, but the thing is that this is an exercise where a, b and c must be integers. And that is why im confused here. But if it would be like you said, to put all the values as doubles, I would understand it.

Comment: just to add to this answer, if you need a float result you should cast at least on argument of the division to float: ((float)(b+c))/(a*a)

Comment: Note: if you perform one explicit conversion like (double)(a * a), (b+c) promoted to double automatically

Answer (score 1):

All your input variables are integers, so the arithmetic is done as integer arithmetic. Also all arithemtic operators in C# are evaluated left to right, so

`e = (b + c) / a * a` is equivalent to `e = ((b + c) / a ) * a`

```
(b + c ) / a * a = ((9 + 2) / 3) * 3
                 = (11 / 3) * 3
                 = 3 * 3
                 = 9
```

The expression that I think you want is

```
e = (double)(b + c) / (a * a);
```

For details on operator precendence in C# see [this .NET documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb387132%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is quite correct - you may want to review how [operator precedence in C# works](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Comment: Your example reads as `9 + 2`, then divided by `3`, dropping the remainder (since they're all `int`s), then multiplying that result by `3`.  There's a gap between the intention and the expression.

Answer (score 0):

You have two choice.Use doubles instead of integers, or use explicit cast and convert one of your values to double

```
 e = (b + c) / (double)(a * a);
```

This statement :

```
(b + c) / a * a
```

evaluated like:

```
(int) / (int)
```

If you divide two integers, how could you get double results ? Then your result converting double with implicit type conversion.But result is already '1' without the floating points,and conversion is meaningless in this case.

But when you do something like this:

```
e = (b + c) / (double)(a * a);
```

Returning value from `b + c` promoted to `double` and then (double / double) division is performing.So you get the correct results.